# error mysql table does not exist

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, lamp, data-files

I have move the data folder of previous install to new install location, phpmyadmin show the database in list but cannot browse table due to error "table does not exist".

It has happened next time and only solution I found is to restore through .sql backup file ( if have any )

Please help if any solution can identify the tables structure and their data...

I am using Bitnami wamp stack, First I installed it on windows 7 in c:\bitnami

Few months later I installed windows 10, then installed bitnami in c:\bitnami again.

I tried to use the old mysql databases in new installation, by copying windows 7 c:\bitnami\mysql\data folder to windows 10 c:\bitnami\mysql\data

after copying phpmyadmin is showing database and their tables but when click on table it says "error mysql table does not exist"

Comment: maybe it would help if you would provide some information?

Comment: Do you have the old machine/install to be able to get the .sql files?  It's a bit late now, but you shouldn't move the mysql data folder from one machine to another.  The upgrade of the machine and new install could result in a slightly newer version of MySQL, and that could mean the files aren't compatible.

Comment: I have backup of mysql data folder as it contains the .frm files of tables